# Connect to API endpoint in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services

My entire app is broken down into 3 parts:

1. Frontend, which is React.
2. Backend, which is API written in the flask language.
3. Database.

I want to host my app on AWS such that my frontend is visible to the world i.e it is in public subnet, API is hidden in a private subnet and then the DB is also in a private subnet. I can communicate with my private API instance using curl in my public frontend instance, but I can not communicate with my API through the React App.

Please help me out.

Comment: Well, yeah. The backend's going to have to be accessible to the client in *some* sort of publicly-accessible manner. Your frontend instance will either need to proxy requests to the API, or you'll need to expose the backend in some sort of public manner (either directly, or behind something like an ELB).

Comment: @ceejayoz How do I proxy requests?

Comment: That'll depend on your webserver and specific setup. It's kinda weird to have your frontend's API non-public, though.

Comment: It is just for training purpose. I am using Nginx as my webserver.

Comment: Look at [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) then. I'm a little baffled that you'd train to do something that wouldn't be done in production, though. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You mean to say that API services are always exposed to the internet? I mean what if some company chooses to use their API for themselves only and not expose it publicly?

Comment: Sure, you could have an internal API that's used for server-to-server stuff. It doesn't make much sense when you're talking about a client-side React app running in a browser, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78250/discussion-between-harith-and-ceejayoz).

Comment: You didn't say anything in chat. Wrong button? (This is why I don't use the chat...)

Comment: I had lost my network connection. I have now replied to you in the chat. But would you like to continue our discussion here?

Comment: I tend to avoid the chat system. Ultimately, if you have a client-side app that uses an API, the client-side needs to be able to *reach* that API somehow. If you put the API in a private subnet, you'll have to have some way to reach it, like an ELB or some sort of proxy.

Comment: I have connected my two API instances to ELB, but that has made them publicly accessible

Comment: Via the ELB, sure. What else were you expecting? You want a JavaScript-based app on the client-side to be able to reach the API. That means it needs to be publicly available *somehow*.